# How can I make the H tag and the P tag responsive under a video

Tags: css, html

I have an embedded video on a web page. The video has a title under it wrapped in the h2 header tag. The video also has text under it wrapped in a P tag. I have made the video responsive so users can view the video using their Mobile phones. However, I don't know how to make the header tag and the paragraph tag responsive. The h1 tag is too big for the cell phone size. I want the font-size smaller based on the width of the screen. How do I make the text responsive under my video. [image: responsive video]

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive design</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.another-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="another-container">
<div class="video-container">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ggh_y-33Eso" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<h1>Learn HTML in 15 Minutes</h1>
<p> Learning html is the foundation for all great webmaster</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'responsive text' exactly? Do you want the text to wrap to a new line (because it already does), or make the font-size smaller based on the width of the screen?

Comment: Please define what you mean by responsive.  The code seems to work, I just can't figure out what it  isn't doing.

Comment: The h1 tag is too big for the cell phone size. I want the font-size smaller based on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries to Handle the h1 and p tag styles.    http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

For example
       
       
       
       
    
    @media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
      color: fuchsia;
    }

```
.desc:after {
  content:" In fact, it's between 500px and 600px wide.";
}
}
</style>
```